# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, typeerror

I have a input textbox with jquery's autocomplete. Whenever I try to interact with the box, no autocompletion alternatives are displayed. In the tools for debugging of Chrome I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined".
When I add an inputtype on the box, the console erros add another one.
thi is the JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $("input#insegnapag").autocomplete({
  delay: 300,
  minLength: 0,
  source: function(request, response) {
  var reqdem = request.term;
  str_data = "insegna=" + reqdem + "&categ=" + $("#categor").val(); // + "&lat=" + $("#lat").val() + "&lng=" + $("#lng").val() ;
   $.ajax({
    url: '/php-cmd/estraiNomiInsegna.php',
    dataType: "json",
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    data: str_data,
    success: function(data) {
      var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data, function(m) {
        return {
          label: m.insegna,
          value: m.insegna
        };
      });
      response(array);
    }
  });
},
focus: function(event, ui) {
  // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).val(ui.item.label);
},
select: function(event, ui) {
  // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
  event.preventDefault();
  // navigate to the selected item's url
  $(this).val(ui.item.label);
  $("#insegnapag").val(ui.item.value);
  $("#insegna").val(ui.item.value);
  }
});
$("input#insegnapag").keydown(function(event) {
 if (event.keyCode === 13) {
  var destination = 'http://www.trovavolantini.it/volantino/' +       $("#insegnapag").val() + '/' + $("#citta").val();
   $("#insegnapag").val($("#insegnapag").val());    
   window.location.href = destination;
   event.preventDefault();     
 }
 });
  $("#citta").keydown(function(event) {

   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var destination = '';
    if ($("#insegnapag").val() == '') {
    destination = 'http://www.trovavolantini.it/volantino-categoria/' + $("#categoria").val() + '/' + $("#citta").val();
   }
  else {
    destination = 'http://www.trovavolantini.it/volantino/' + $("#insegnapag").val() + '/' + $("#citta").val();
   }
   $("#localita").val($("#citta").val());
   $("#citta").val($("#citta").val());
   //alert ($("#localita").val());
   window.location.href = destination;
   event.preventDefault();
   //  return false;
  }
});
```

this is part of the .PHP file with the include files:

```
  <link href="/css/global-res.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/css/insegna-dk.css" media="(min-width:1080px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:1080px)" href="/css/insegna-small-650.css" type="text/css">                  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
      <link href="/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:1080px)" href="/css/global-small-650.css" type="text/css"/>          

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-516ecf974aa275c4" async></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript" async ></script>        
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&region=it&language=it&sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.trovavolantini.it/js/utility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/volantino.js"></script>
     <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

and part of the code for the input text:

```
<form id="form2" metod="POST" action="">
                  <h2 style="z-index:10;" class="menu-loc"><strong>Offerte <?php echo $VolCat; ?> <span class="tooltip" title="Cerca un'insegna"><input type="text" class="selectcity" id="insegnapag" value="<?php echo $insegna; ?>"/></span> vicino a 
                      <span class="tooltip" title="Non sei qui? Cambia"><input type="text" class="selectcity" id="citta" value="<?php echo $localita; ?>"/><input type="hidden" id="idloc" name="idloc"/></span>
                      <input type="hidden" id="localita" name="localita" value="<?php echo $localita; ?>" />
                      <!--<input type="hidden" id="insegna" name="insegna" value="<?php echo $insegna; ?>" />--> </strong>

                    <span style="font-size:0.8em"><a href="javascript:newUrl();"  id="cambia_localita">
                        <span>Cambia</span></a></span><img src="/images/puntatore-citta.png"  title="Volantino <?php echo $insegna; ?> vicino a <?php echo $localita; ?>" alt="Volantino <?php echo $insegna; ?> vicino a <?php echo $localita; ?>" width="26" height="40" align="absmiddle" /><a href="javascript:geolocalizzami()" id="Geolocalizza"><img src="/images/sono-qui.png" style="padding-left: 45px" align="absmiddle" alt="Sono qui!" title="Sono qui!"/></a></h2>

                  <input type="hidden" id="localitachange_data" name="localita" value="<?php echo $localita; ?>"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="<?php echo $lat_curr; ?>"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="<?php echo $lng_curr; ?>"/>
                  <input type="hidden" id="categor" name="categor" value="<?php echo $idcat; ?>"/>
   </form>
```

you can see all this on 
       http://www.trovavolantini.it/volantino-categoria/Iper%20e%20Super

Comment: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." - says it all mate.

Comment: Can you debug the ajax call response and check that the `array` variable is filled correctly before being passed to the `response` function?

Comment: @Roberto Linares: return an array of Objects. Each Object has label and value field. But ther is the same error.  "Cannot read property 'element' of undefined".